# Prove that the sum is divisible by $7$

Tags: number-theory

> Prove that if $m$ is an odd positive integer not divisible by $3$, then $$4^m-2\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{m-1}{2}} \binom{m}{2k}2^{m-k}$$ is divisible by $7$.

Since $4^m \equiv 4,2,1,\ldots \pmod{7}$, we take two cases: $m \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$ and $m \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$. In the first case, $m = 1+6k$ and so $4^m \equiv 4 \pmod{7}$ and in the second case, $m = 2+3(1+2k) = 5+6k$ and so $4^m \equiv 2 \pmod{7}$. How do we continue from here?

Note: Solving this question also solves part of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1891213/prove-that-112-divides-the-integral-part-of-4m-2-sqrt2m) question.

Comment: Is there some context to this? I ask specifically since it seems related to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1891213/prove-that-112-divides-the-integral-part-of-4m-2-sqrt2m

Comment: @quid It is related to it.

Comment: So what is the relation?

Comment: @quid It solves part of the problem.

Comment: So you are seeking an alternative approach to that problem? Maybe explain that in the post.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaking, the sequence given is $4^m - u_m$ where
$$ u_m = (2+\sqrt{2})^m + (2-\sqrt{2})^m $$
The characteristic equation is $\lambda^2 - 4 \lambda +2=0$ so we
have 
$$ u_{m+2}=4u_{m+1}-2 u_m \ \ \ \mbox{or} \ \ \
  \left( \begin{matrix} u_{m+2} \\ u_{m+1} \end{matrix} \right)
=
\left( \begin{matrix} 4 & -2  \\ 1 & 0  \end{matrix} \right)
\left( \begin{matrix} u_{m+1} \\ u_{m} \end{matrix} \right) $$
Write $M$ for the 2 by 2 matrix. Then $M^6 \equiv {\bf 1}$ mod 7 and thus, $u_{m+6}\equiv u_m$ mod 7. Since also $4^6\equiv 1$ mod 7 it suffices to verify the claim for $1\leq m \leq 6$. Then it is automatically verified when adding multiples of 6.

Comment: How did you get $M^6 \equiv 1 \pmod{7}$?

Comment: @Puzzled417: Maybe by computing $M^6$ ? :)

Comment: You may do it by hand, but in fact I just plugged it into scilab (something alike matlab) and calculated mod 7.